# Client error in RSelenium ( R programming)

Tags: r, google-chrome, web-scraping, rselenium, netstat

Hello I hope you are well

I was programming doing data scrapping, using the R package (RSelenium)

Currently, I am programming in the version of R 4.2.3

`library(RSelenium)`
`library(netstat)`
`library(tidyverse)`
`library(rvest)`
`library(sys)`

First, I use the following commands to find out the exact versions of both Chrome and Selenium server

```
binman::list_versions('chromedriver')
binman::list_versions("seleniumserver")
RSelenium::checkForServer()
```

Defines the URL
`url <- "https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g294074-i3499-k13204080-Safety-Bogota.html"`

The problem lies with the following code

```
rs_driver_object <- rsDriver(
  browser = "chrome",
  chromever = "113.0.5672.63",
  verbose = F, #supres anay messsage 
  port = free_ports() #the unic function we use from nestat
)
```

and the error it generates is

```
[1] Could not open chrome browser.
Client error message:
Undefined error in httr call. httr output: Failed to connect to localhost port 14415 after 2253 ms: Connection refused
Check server log for further details.
Warning message:
In rsDriver(browser = "chrome", chromever = "113.0.5672.63", verbose = F,  :
  Could not determine server status.
```

I have not understood the problem, I hope for a prompt response, and I thank you in advance for the use of your time.

We hope to be able to activate the RSelenium, to be able to work in a Chrome tab. It provides a "shim" for the current issue running firefox on Windows. For a more detailed set of functions for running binaries relating to the Selenium/webdriver project see the wdman package. Both the client and server are closed using a registered finalizer.

Comment: 1. Try using 'firefox' 2. Delete license file in `C:\Users\Jeff\AppData\Local\binman\binman_chromedriver\win32`.